# Как передать параметры в ShockwaveFlash?

Tags: delphi, flash

Начну с того, что у меня имеется ссылка на swf проигрыватель в интернете, и по параметру ему передается имя  файла, для воспроизведения, например вот:

> http://img0.imgsmail.ru/r/my/player3.swf?file=http://music11.my.mail.ru/file/9e51b33d4f5c917dc4a6448991d127a7.mp3

Через ShockwaveFlash открывает только сам плеер, но не воспроизводит; любые другие ролики в инете без параметров воспроизводит прекрасно, как реализовать передачу параметра? Или может есть другой способ воспроизвести этот swf вместе с файлом у меня в программе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю

> `?file=http://music11.my.mail.ru/file/9e51b33d4f5c917dc4a6448991d127a7.mp3`

это GET параметр для веб; то, что опера или мозила передают его swf проигрывателю, - это заслуга их разработчиков.

А делфи использует ActiveX компоненту, т.е. то же, что и IE, (кстати, в IE ваш линк тоже не проигрывает).

А параметры передаются через ShockwaveFlash1.FlashVars и через методы методов SetVariable и GetVariable.

Вот довольно интересная статья на эту тему: [Flash и Delphi](http://citforum.ru/internet/flash/flash_delphi/).

Comment: Статья интересная, спасибо, но не могли бы вы поподробнее, на примере, там пример локальный... я просмотрел, попробовал с GetVariable и SetVariable, мне выдает: "Неопознанная ошибка"( Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Сперва нужно добиться, чтоб swf файл работал в ИЕ.
Чтоб GetVariable и SetVariable, нужно прерывание из флэш файла
и точно знать название переменной, в которую нужно передавать.
А для конретно работающего примера нужен .fla файл.

Comment: Никак не могу разобраться. (

Comment: Лучше поэкспириментируйте сперва на локальном swf файл исходники которого под рукой.

Comment: Представьте, только сейчас понял, что доступ к mp3 файлам был по "печенькам" (cookies), а про GetVariable большое спасибо, помогло уже давно сделал. Только щас написал - потому что инета не было( Спасибо за ответы!